# Set values of a matrix on positions inside a triangle

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a N x N matrix will all values equal to zero, then I need to get the coordinates of a triangle and set the values inside this triangle to one (1).

How can I determine the position of each element in the matrix that forms the triangle faces?

Like this 10x10 matrix, I have a triangle set at (9,1),(5,5) and (9,5):

```
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000010000
0000110000
0001010000
0010010000
0111110000
```

I don't need the code made for me, I want to check if there is a proper way (maybe using math) to get the "coordinates".

Comment: Wait, so you know, for example, `(9,5)` and `(5,5)` and you're looking how to find `(8,5), (7,5), (6,5)`? Except the ones not trivial like parallel to an axis like that?

Comment: I would use a line drawing algorithm like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two points x1,y1 and x2,y2, you can use these to create a formula for the line using "point-slope form"

Calculate slope with `m = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)`

Then you have a formula of `y - y1 = m(x - x1)`

This further goes to `y = m(x - x1) + y1`

So in your example of `(9,1),(5,5)` you calculate the `m = (1 - 5) / (9 - 5) = (-4) / (4) = -1`

Then your formula becomes, for that line, `y = (-1)(x - 9) + 1`

Then iterate between 5 and 9.

```
f(5) = -(5-9) + 1 = -(-4) + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5
f(6) = -(6-9) + 1 = -(-3) + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4
f(7) = -(7-9) + 1 = -(-2) + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
f(8) = -(8-9) + 1 = -(-1) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
f(9) = -(9-9) + 1 = -(0)) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Triangles have nice properties allowing a very simple algorithm to suffice.

Find Ymax, the topmost Y coordinate set in the triangle. Then for Ymax, find Xmin and Xmax, of the left and rightmost pixels set in that row. Now there are 2 cases. If Xmin == Xmax, then one vertex is (Xmin,Ymax), otherwise two of the coordinates are (Xmin, Ymax) and (Xmax, Ymax).

With this you've found the topmost coordinate or coordinates.

It's pretty simple to continue this reasoning to find the other ones. I'll let you puzzle it out for the fun...

You can combine the min and max-finding in the algorithm above with the algorithm that does the filling as required in the second part of the problem.